# What does "pcr" stand for?

Tags: notation, terminology

For example, as shown in [this OEIS page](http://oeis.org/A001400):

$P(n,4)=\frac{2n^3+6n^2-9n-13+(9n+9)\text{pcr}\{1,-1\}(2,n)-32\text{pcr}\{1,-1,0\}(3,n)-36\text{pcr}\{1,0,-1,0\}(4,n)}{288}$

Comment: It references Comtet at the end of that bit, and Googling that text I find that it corresponds to a "prime circulator" so named by Cayley. What that means...? It seems pretty obscure.

Comment: You can find a discussion [here](https://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/h25/h25.pdf)  though I can't say it is entirely clear (at least on first reading).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\operatorname{pcr}T_n$ means the $n$-th term of a periodic sequence with the terms as given (starting from index 0). [A001400](http://oeis.org/A001400) refers to [1]:

> We denote the periodic sequence with period $T$ (integer $\ge1$), that is equal to $d_i$ for $n\equiv i\pmod T$, $i=0,1,\ldots,T-1$, by: $(d_0,d_1,\ldots,d_{T-1})\operatorname{cr}T_n$ (cr for *circulator*; this notation is from Herschel). If, moreover, for each divisor $S$ of $T$, $1\le S\le T$, we have $d_R+d_{R+S}+d_{R+2S}+\cdots+d_{R+T-S}=0$ for all $R=0,1,2,\ldots,S-1$, then we rather denote the above sequence by $(d_0,d_1,\ldots,d_{T-1})\operatorname{pcr}T_n$ (pcr stands for *prime circulator*, the notation is due to Cayley)

I can't find the original paper, but Sylvester [2] also attributes this to Cayley. Sylvester prefers the term "prime circulator" to Calyey's "prime radical circulator".

[1] Louis Comtet, Advanced Combinatorics: The Art of Finite and Infinite Expansions (1974)

[2] J. J. Sylvester, On the partition of numbers, *The Quarterly Journal of Pure and Applied Mathematics* **1** (1857), pp. 141–152. See [p. 150](https://books.google.com/books?id=zHGi04-IKNIC&lpg=PA150&ots=1qcGMmcElp&pg=PA150#v=onepage&q&f=false)